# Add additional parameter to the spring security oauth token request

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0, webclient

I'm trying to create a logic for oauth2 with spring security. The grant_type is client_credentials. Server I'm trying to make connect with requires an additional parameter within access_token request (except client_id and client_secret), account_id.

Project details:
spring-boot- 3.0.X

This is request required by customclient to get the token:

uri: xxxxxxx/token

```
{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "xxxx",
    "client_secret": "xxxxxxxx",
    "account_id": "123456789"
}
```

I found some useful documentation and this is what I was able to implement so far. But there is one problem  with I'm struggling now and couldn't find the solution. How add additional parameter (account_id in this case) to the token request?

application.yml

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          custom-client:
            provider: custom-client
            client-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            client-secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-authentication-method: post
        provider:
          custom-client:
            token-uri: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/token
```

WebClientConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager webclientManager(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                           OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build();

        AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient customWebClient(@Qualifier("webclientManager") OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oAuth2Filer = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oAuth2Filer.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("customclient");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oAuth2Filer)
                .baseUrl(apiUrl)
                .build();
    }

}
```

This is an example service where I would like to use webClient to make some REST call:

MyService.java

```
@Service
public class MyService{

    WebClient webClient;

    public MyService(@Qualifier("customClient") WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    public String testRequest() {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri("xxxxxx")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
    }
}
```

I was trying to add it somehow to the security-oauth2-client-registration-custom-client but without the success. I couldn't find a place where I can add additional parameters.

Comment: I've just found one solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72362533/oauth2-client-with-extra-parameters-in-body-audience and it's working.

I would be grateful if someone has any other, smarter way to do it.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/authorization-grants.html#_customizing_the_authorization_request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For info, I have added a more concise and non deprecated (in spring 2.7 and 3.1) solution to the post you mentioned in your comment:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76652811/19623995