# how to add additional token request (resource) to crm dynamics api integration in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, dynamics-crm

Need to integrate CRM API in spring boot. I am facing challenge as to how to configure/add additional token request(resource: xyz-dynamics.com), key-value , sent in request body to generate token.

Comment: Found answer to the above :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72362533/oauth2-client-with-extra-parameters-in-body-audience

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your trying to do, you will want to review one of these flows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

if your connecting to PowerPlatform (Dataverse API - some folk still call it CRMAPI), one of the key things that trips folks up most of the time is setting the resource correctly.
The resource / scope you use must be set to the org URL including trailing /.

The Online system will tell you what to use for this if you ask it by querying the API endpoint without authentication.  the response will include a www-authenticate header that includes the Resource name and Authority you need to contact to get a token for that environment.

You can see a code example of this in the Dataverse ServiceClient (.net Client Lib provided by Microsoft) here: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatform-DataverseServiceClient/blob/90998e3ffbf7e6bc25cd0ff82a15c0f0dbcff049/src/GeneralTools/DataverseClient/Client/Auth/AuthorityResolver.cs#L67C74-L67C74