# calling the Auth0 API with Spring Boot using Oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, auth0, okta

I have a Spring Boot 3 service that uses Auth0/Okta to secure its API. The users get a token and can call my endpoints. I am using these parameters in my application.yaml :

```
okta:
  oauth2:
    audience: 
    issuer:
```

My service also needs to be able to call Auth0, to be able to create a user for instance, using OAuth2 token

Things are properly setup on the Auth0 side, because I am able to make the call with Postman, after retrieving a token using clientId and clientSecret that were issued for my service.

I assumed it would be straightforward to do with the SDK and starter and embed this in my service, but I am not finding the way to achieve that :

- https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java is giving an example of how to do that using an apiToken

[image]

and through a private key :

[image]

- on https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot/?tab=readme-ov-file#inject-the-okta-java-sdk , it also indicates how to use the SDK, using an API token

[image]

I could not find any resource on how to achieve something similar, with Oauth2.

When I try it "manually", by setting up more code myself, I am failing to get a token, because Auth0 requires an `audience` parameter, that is not supported out of the box by Spring Security (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6569)

I was expecting this to be very easy given how Spring Boot and Auth0 are popular, but it turns out I am not finding a single example of this working more or less out of the box with Spring Boot 3 / Spring Security 6..

In the end, these were useful resources :

- [OAuth2 client with extra parameters in body (Audience)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72362533/oauth2-client-with-extra-parameters-in-body-audience) , which pointed to :
- https://www.aheritier.net/spring-boot-app-client-of-an-auth0-protected-service-jwt/

Did I miss anything in the docs, or is there truly no better way of calling the Auth0 API with OAuth2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just went through this exercise, so allow me to help.

First, let me say that I went down the route of using the okta SDK but I didn't have a good experience with it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.okta</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

1. It didn't integrate well with the Spring Framework.
2. Why not use openID-Connect and OAuth2 libraries since they are more compatible with, well, openid-connect and oauth2. Makes it much easier to switch to different OpenId/OAuth2 providers, KeyCloak.

I also used [Auth0 by Okta](https://auth0.com/) oauth2 service since it is a free developer oriented platform.

My project used Spring security dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Since you are only interested in the Resource Server made a quick project for that.

Add this to your application.yml.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: ${auth0audience-issuer-uri}
          audiences: ${auth0audience-audience}
      client:
        registration:
          auth0:
            client-id: ${auth0audience-client-id}
            client-secret: ${auth0audience-client-secret}
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            provider: auth0
        provider:
          auth0:
            issuer-uri: ${auth0audience-issuer-uri}
```

Then configure the `SecurityFilterChain` to require authentication and use `JWT` access tokens for authentication.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())).build();
    }
}
```

As you have found out though, the difficulty really is in accessing it through `WebClient`. Spring security must be configured to add the `audience` parameter to the request headers when requesting an access token to use with the API. This is important because the access token must have the `aud` property when it is issued. This really means configurating the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` to have a `DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient` that is configured to add the `audience` parameter to the request for an access token. This client is invoked auto-magically in the background when there is a need for a new access token.

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.audiences}")
    private String audience;

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
                new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);

        return WebClient.builder()
                .apply(oauth2Client.oauth2Configuration())
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .clientCredentials((builder) ->
                                builder.accessTokenResponseClient(clientCredentialsAccessTokenResponseClient())
                                        .build())
                        .build();

        AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    private OAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest> clientCredentialsAccessTokenResponseClient() {
        DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient accessTokenResponseClient =
                new DefaultClientCredentialsTokenResponseClient();

        OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequestEntityConverter requestEntityConverter =
                new OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequestEntityConverter();
        requestEntityConverter.addParametersConverter(source -> CollectionUtils.toMultiValueMap(Collections.singletonMap("audience", Collections.singletonList(audience))));
        accessTokenResponseClient.setRequestEntityConverter(requestEntityConverter);

        return accessTokenResponseClient;
    }

}
```

Then you can use it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Auth0WebClientAudienceApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Auth0WebClientAudienceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    WebClient webClient;
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        List<String> r = webClient.get().uri("movies")
                .attributes(clientRegistrationId("auth0"))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {
                }).block();
        System.out.println("movies = " + r);
    }
}
```

The special need here is the line `.attributes(clientRegistrationId("auth0"))` which tells the webclient which client the client manager should use to get the access token before making the call to the API. It's all very well hidden with minimal documentation.

The code for the API is nothing special. This example does not attempt to demonstrate authorization.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class MovieApi {
    @GetMapping("movies")
    public List<String> getMovies() {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        if (!(securityContext instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            return List.of("movie1", "movie2");
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Git repo of this code at [Auth0WebClientAudience](https://github.com/karlnicholas/Auth0WebClientAudience).

Spring Security Framework has some documenation at [OAuth 2.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html).

Comment: thanks, I confirm it works for me ! just one small thing that annoys me a bit : is there a way to move the .attributes(clientRegistrationId("auth0")) into the webclient when we build it ? because all the calls I am making with it should have this, so I would like to avoid specifying it for each request

Comment: Not sure. What happens when you try it?

Comment: I am not finding a directly equivalent method on WebClient.builder(), so I am not able to try

Comment: @k-nicholas, that was true that the other answers applied to authorization-code and had little interest in the case of an Auth0 API call from a Spring application configured mainly as a resource server. I fixed mine to better cover the use case and I believe that you could find some interest in it (very simple while respecting your concern for a solution working with any OpenID Provider)

Answer (score 0):

I'll expose here an answer using a [Spring Boot starter of mine](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc#spring-addons-starter-oidc) in addition to `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` and [available from maven-central](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.c4-soft.springaddons/spring-addons-starter-oidc):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

With this dependency, we won't need a single line of Java for security configuration (all done with just properties).

Also, there is a choice of REST client to use in a Spring application:

- `RestTemplate`: in maintenance mode, you should probably avoid it in new applications / services
- `WebClient`: better adapted to reactive (Weflux) applications like `spring-cloud-gateway`
- `RestClient`: supposed to be the equivalent of `WebClient` for servlets, but it was introduced only very recently and isn't as mature (for instance, providing functions to add a `Bearer` token in the `Authorization` header is not trivial)
- `@FeignClient`: provided by Spring Cloud, it is my favorite and the one I'll use in this answer:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2023.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### Sample Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApiController {
    private final Auth0Api auth0;

    @GetMapping("/api/user-count")
    public UserCountDto getUserCount(JwtAuthenticationToken auth) {
        return new UserCountDto(auth0.getTotalUsers());
    }

    public static record UserCountDto(Long totalUsers) {}
}
```

### Sample `@FeignClient`

```java
@FeignClient(name = "auth0-api")
public interface Auth0Api {

    default Long getTotalUsers() {
        return getUsers(true, 0).total();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/users")
    Auth0UserPageDto getUsers(@RequestParam("include_totals") boolean includeTotals, @RequestParam("per_page") int perPage);

    public static record Auth0UserPageDto(Long total) {}
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients
public class FeignConfiguration {}
```

### Using Client Credentials

As this is what you ask, here is a way to use client-credentials (but you should read next section).

```yaml
issuer: https://dev-ch4mpy.eu.auth0.com/
client-id: change-me
client-secret: change-me

spring:
  cloud:
    openfeign:
      client:
        config:
          auth0-api:
            url: ${issuer}api/v2
      oauth2:
        enabled: true
        clientRegistrationId: auth0-backend
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          auth0:
            issuer-uri: ${issuer}
        registration:
          auth0-backend:
            provider: auth0
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-id: ${client-id}
            client-secret: ${client-secret}
            scope: read:users
com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${issuer}
        client:
          token-request-params:
            auth0-backend:
            - name: audience
              value: https://dev-ch4mpy.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/
        resourceserver:
          permit-all:
          - /**
```

Again, no Java conf. It is also intentional that `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver` is missing (replaced with `com.c4-soft.springaddons.oidc.ops` which is an array and can accept as many issuers as we trust).

Because of `com.c4-soft.springaddons.oidc.token-request-params.auth0-backend` being present, a custom `(Reactive)OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` is registered, adding the extra parameters we need to the token request

Note the 3 occurrences of `auth0-backend` (1st and 3rd are references to the 2nd):

1. as value for `spring.cloud.openfeign.oauth2.clientRegistrationId` property
2. as OAuth2 client registration (key for an entry in `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration`)
3. as registration for which additional parameter(s) should be added to token requests (key for an entry in `com.c4-soft.springaddons.oidc.client.token-request-params`)

Also note that because of `permit-all: /**`, there is no need for the request to be authorized to query the Spring `@RestController` (but, of course, the request from the Spring `@RestController` to Auth0 API is authorized with a token fetched using client-credentials).

### Forwarding the Original Request Authorization

For quite a few reasons, including efficiency and traceability (keep track of who called Auth0 API), when a request to your Spring `@RestController` is initiated by a user who has enough rights to perform the Auth0 API call, rather than getting a new access token using client credentials, you'd better forward the access token you received with the request.

With `@FeignClient`, you can use a `RequestInterceptor` for that:

```java
public class JwtForwardingRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuth) {
            template.header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer %s".formatted(jwtAuth.getToken().getTokenValue()));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the security configuration to use:

```yaml
issuer: https://dev-ch4mpy.eu.auth0.com/
client-id: change-me
client-secret: change-me

spring:
  cloud:
    openfeign:
      client:
        config:
          auth0-api:
            url: ${issuer}api/v2
            request-interceptors:
            - com.c4soft.feign.JwtForwardingRequestInterceptor
com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${issuer}
```

Note that `spring.security.oauth2.client` as well as `com.c4-soft.springaddons.oidc.client` are gone. You could also remove the dependency on `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`.

Also, this time there is no `permit-all: /**`, which means that only authorized requests can access the `@RestController` (otherwise we wouldn't have any access token to forward with the request to Auth0 API)

Answer (score -1):

There is [an open issue](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot/issues/596) for the Okta Spring Boot starter that shows how to add an `audience` parameter to the `/authorize` request.

Here's how to do it with Spring Security for Spring MVC:

```java
package com.example.apigateway;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${okta.oauth2.audience}")
    private String audience;

    private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    public SecurityConfiguration(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .authorizationEndpoint(authorization -> authorization
                    .authorizationRequestResolver(
                        authorizationRequestResolver(this.clientRegistrationRepository)
                    )
                )
            );
        return http.build();
    }

    private OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver(
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {

        DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver =
            new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
                clientRegistrationRepository, "/oauth2/authorization");
        authorizationRequestResolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(
            authorizationRequestCustomizer());

        return authorizationRequestResolver;
    }

    private Consumer<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.Builder> authorizationRequestCustomizer() {
        return customizer -> customizer
            .additionalParameters(params -> params.put("audience", audience));
    }
}
```

And here's the code for Spring WebFlux:

```java
package com.example.apigateway;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AuthorizationRequest;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${okta.oauth2.audience}")
    private String audience;

    private final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    public SecurityConfiguration(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain filterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeExchange(authz -> authz
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .authorizationRequestResolver(
                    authorizationRequestResolver(this.clientRegistrationRepository)
                )
            );
        return http.build();
    }

    private ServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver(
        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {

        DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver authorizationRequestResolver =
            new DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
                clientRegistrationRepository);
        authorizationRequestResolver.setAuthorizationRequestCustomizer(
            authorizationRequestCustomizer());

        return authorizationRequestResolver;
    }

    private Consumer<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.Builder> authorizationRequestCustomizer() {
        return customizer -> customizer
            .additionalParameters(params -> params.put("audience", audience));
    }
}
```

I learned how to do this from [Spring Security's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html#oauth2-client-customize-request-parameters).