# How to add the "audience" attribute to the request body of the token request with FeignClient and OAuth2 in Spring Boot (Kotlin)?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud-feign, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

I am currently using Feign, a declarative REST client, with OAuth2 in my Spring Boot (Kotlin) application. To specify the client provider and registration, I use the `application.yml` properties file with the `grant_type` set to `client_credentials` and the `token-uri` endpoint set to `https://url/oauth/token`.

**Error:**
A `403 (Forbidden)` error message stating that `No audience parameter was provided...` because the `audience` attribute is missing from the request body.

Is it possible to add the `audience` attribute with a URL value to the token request using FeignClient and OAuth2 in Spring Boot (Kotlin) via configuration properties or do I need to create a custom bean?

I have tried adding the `audience` attribute using custom parameters in the header and query params, but this did not work. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html#oauth2-client-customize-request-parameters

I need to add the `audience` attribute with a value to the **request body** of the token request.

To enable OAuth2 support, I am using this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#oauth2-support.

To add the `audience` attribute to the request body, I need to provide it in the following format:

POST call to `/oauth/token`:

```json
{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "id",
    "client_secret": "secret",
    "audience": "https://url"
}
```

The response should be in the following format:

```json
{
    "access_token": "token",
    "expires_in": 86400,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Good to mention that I'm not the owner of the Authentication (0Auth) server and therefore cannot provide a default `audience` or make any changes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77950804/619830

Comment: Hi @ch4mp, thank you for your suggestion and willingness to help! Unfortunately, my company has a strict policy on using libraries, so I can't use your custom Spring Boot starter. I've built a custom implementation with an extra FeignClient and Caffeine caching, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution using Spring Security. Do you have any other suggestions or workarounds? Thank you for your help!

Comment: My starter is open-source and uses solely dependencies managed by Spring Boot "official" starters. Just look at the beans I define in it, what you need to do now (and maintain after that) is just some of what is done in this starter.